# Android gmap utils clusterer update marker position after clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing

I have a simple android google map that implements the gmap utils clustering.

My markers are also set to draggable, which works fine.

The problem is, after dragging I zoom out and the markers cluster, but after zooming in the marker that I dragged is in the initial spot it was in when I created it, not where I dragged it to.

How does one update a marker's position in the cluster collection?

Calling mClusterManager.cluster() in the onMarkerDragEnd() event doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (although as usual, it just brought up more questions)

Apparently the GMap utils library was updated to expose a method that allows you to get a cluster item via the cluster manager.

So, first, create a temporary storage variable for the marker being moved:

```
private ClusterItem tempCM;
```

Next, drop the marker into that storage variable on drag start:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    tempCM = customRenderer.getClusterItem(marker);
}
```

Finally, remove that marker from the cluster manager and add the newly updated marker on drag end:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    ClusterMarker newCM = new ClusterMarker(marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude,marker.getTitle(),marker.getSnippet());
    mClusterManager.removeItem((ClusterMarker)tempCM);
    mClusterManager.addItem(newCM);

    mClusterManager.cluster();
}
```

Unfortunately this dumps the custom icon I had setup for the marker, but that's another thread.  Hope this helps.

Comment: How have you enabled Marker dragging using Clustser Manager?